# React Slick, Slider disappears when arrows are false

Tags: reactjs, slider, carousel, react-slick

I'm using react-slick in one of my projects and for some reason when I turn off arrows the entire slider disappears

The code is looking like this

```
       <div className="container" style={{position: "relative", padding: 0}}>
            <div className={styles.class_name}>

            </div>
            <Slider onSwipe={this.swipeHandler} arrows={false}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Slider>
        </div>
```

I'm using customized Bootstrap with only responsive utilities and grid.

Any help, suggestion etc would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the `sliderSettings` values to your question and show how you are turning on/off the arrows?

Comment: I only setted arrows to false

Comment: Is `arrows={false}}` a typo or do you actually have the extra trailing `}` in your code?

Comment: It was my typo from editing